# How to pass props to component when used with Quasar dialog plugin

Tags: vue.js, quasar

According to [quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#Dialog-API) the custom component used with `dialog plugin` can have `props`. But I don't see how to pass those props to the component via

```
this.$q.dialog({component: CustomComponent,})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#Invoking-custom-component) state you can add them after the comma like this:

```
  this.$q.dialog({
  component: CustomComponent,

  // optional if you want to have access to
  // Router, Vuex store, and so on, in your
  // custom component:
  parent: this, // becomes child of this Vue node
                // ("this" points to your Vue component)
                // (prop was called "root" in < 1.1.0 and
                // still works, but recommending to switch
                // to the more appropriate "parent" name)

  // props forwarded to component
  // (everything except "component" and "parent" props above):
  text: 'something',
  // ...more.props...
```

Comment: So the 'text' is the prop to the 'CustomComponent'. Thanks